How to use NavigationMixin to set Article to view
Have built a sidebar for Article Detail page in community, where you can click link and have a different article presented.  So far, all efforts to use the NavigationMixin have failed so hoping someone can help me correct this.  There seems no way to debug what leads to the redirect to 'error' page.
On the page (autogenerated by SF), the API Name is 'Article_Detail' and the url is '/article/:urlName'
the following errors out, despite having a published article with api name 'Second-article' and a recordId that is correct.
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                name: 'Article_Detail'
            },
            state:{
                urlName:'Second-article'
            },
            defaultFieldValues: {
                recordId:this.selected
            }
        });

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

For reference, this worked:
// at top of lwc controller
import basePath from '@salesforce/community/basePath';  

then this later on to do the redirect
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: `${basePath}/blog/post?blogId=${event.currentTarget.dataset.id}`
        }
    });

